# 'Partial data load' terminology

Tags: terminology, loading, data, file-format

I am writing up my work and I'm trying to think of a word, or phrase, that better describes a 'partial load' of data.

In my case, I have one very large file that is "environment A". To improve the handling of my data (and to stop my PC crashing) I only load a small section of this environment at once. I do not split the data into different files.

Is there a term that more concisely describes this technique of data handling rather than a 'partial load'?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the accepted term is `streaming`. But this term is too broad, you need to add additional keywords to search, such as `game map streaming loading`. [This is an example of streaming](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16145/help-streaming-resources-maps-sounds-music-etc-from-many-files-for-contiguo). It emphasizes a continuous, smooth loading process.

Personally I prefer `lazy loading`. It emphasizes loading only when necessary.

Or `progressive loading`. It comes from web front-end development, implying different loading priorities and providing placeholders.

Comment: I've also seen "level streaming" used this way.

Comment: Thank you very much. These examples definitely get closer to the process I'm trying to describe.